Laravel api resource return error, when pass null. It should handle null value
// controller
$reseller_id = 903;
$reseller_setting = ResellerSetting::where("reseller_id", $reseller_id)->first();
return ResellerSettingResource::make($reseller_setting);

// resource
class ResellerSettingResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
        ];
    }
}

if $reseller_setting is null. then get below error. Is Laravel api resource handle this type of scenario when pass empty object or null to resource .

ErrorException: Attempt to read property "id" on null in
/home/alzaf-dev/project/isp-manage-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/DelegatesToResource.php:139
Stack trace:
#0
/home/alzaf-dev/project/isp-manage-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(255):
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() ...............

How can I overcome this error?
Laravel API resource error, when pass null object. I don't know how to solve this error.

I can use if else condition before call resource. but i think this is not a good solution.

I'm not really sure what's the logic behind this. You first find a record, and then create it again? Can you elaborate your logic a bit please

i'm trying to find data from database. after that call api resource to format data. when query return data, then did not get any error.  if query return null, then get these error from resource.

You are doing a query (where("reseller_id", $reseller_id)->first();) that might return null. What exactly is the question? Why not check if its null before proceeding? You are not leveraging laravels upcast/ dependency injection here at all

Why not do a firstOrFail and if the reseller setting not found you will get a 404

It should handle null value - why? where? how? there are questions only the developer can answer, not the framework

generally the API should not return an empty object, but a 404 response in this case
